# Translate text to numbers with coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, coordinate-systems, coordinate

I thought of making something for fun today and decided to make a simple program that'll translate a peace of text into numbers. I tried this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AlphaNumCrypt
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public String input;
    public String output;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void translateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Encrypt/Decrypt input
        if (toText.Checked == true)
        {
            // Decrypt input
            input = "";
            input = inputTextBox.Text.ToString();
            decrypt();
        }
        else if (toAlphaNum.Checked == true)
        {
            // Encrypt input
            input = "";
            input = inputTextBox.Text.ToString();
            encrypt();
        }
    }

    private void encrypt()
    {
        // Encrypt the plain text input
        output = input;
        output.Replace("a", "11");
        output.Replace("b", "12");
        output.Replace("c", "13");
        output.Replace("d", "14");
        output.Replace("e", "15");
        output.Replace("f", "16");
        output.Replace("g", "17");
        output.Replace("h", "18");
        output.Replace("i", "19");
        output.Replace("j", "21");
        output.Replace("k", "22");
        output.Replace("l", "23");
        output.Replace("m", "24");
        output.Replace("n", "25");
        output.Replace("o", "26");
        output.Replace("p", "27");
        output.Replace("q", "28");
        output.Replace("r", "29");
        output.Replace("s", "31");
        output.Replace("t", "32");
        output.Replace("u", "33");
        output.Replace("v", "34");
        output.Replace("w", "35");
        output.Replace("x", "36");
        output.Replace("y", "37");
        output.Replace("z", "38");
        output.Replace("æ", "39");
        output.Replace("ø", "41");
        output.Replace("å", "42");
        outputTextBox.Text = output;
    }

    private void decrypt()
    {
        // Decrypt the AlphaNum input
        output = input;
        output.Replace("11", "a");
        output.Replace("12", "b");
        output.Replace("13", "c");
        output.Replace("14", "d");
        output.Replace("15", "e");
        output.Replace("16", "f");
        output.Replace("17", "g");
        output.Replace("18", "h");
        output.Replace("19", "i");
        output.Replace("21", "j");
        output.Replace("22", "k");
        output.Replace("23", "l");
        output.Replace("24", "m");
        output.Replace("25", "n");
        output.Replace("26", "o");
        output.Replace("27", "p");
        output.Replace("28", "q");
        output.Replace("29", "r");
        output.Replace("31", "s");
        output.Replace("32", "t");
        output.Replace("33", "u");
        output.Replace("34", "v");
        output.Replace("35", "w");
        output.Replace("36", "x");
        output.Replace("37", "y");
        output.Replace("38", "z");
        output.Replace("39", "æ");
        output.Replace("41", "ø");
        output.Replace("42", "å");
        outputTextBox.Text = output;
    }
}
}
```

But for some reason the output is equal to the input, what am I doing wrong here?

Regards,
Erik

Comment: Just want to be sure - this is just for fun and doesn't provide a lick of security.

Comment: `string` is immutable when you call replace it returns a new string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't use the result of the `output.Replace` method. It returns a new string and doesn't modify an existing. You should modify your code as follows:

```
output = output.Replace("a", "11");
...
```

**UPDATE**. To make a code more convenient you can store your conversion rules as the array of `Tuple<string, string>`. Thus you can use loops to encode and decode a text. Here is an example:

```
private readonly Tuple<string, string>[] rules = new[]
    {
        new Tuple<string, string>("a", "11"),
        new Tuple<string, string>("b", "12"),
        new Tuple<string, string>("c", "13"),
        ...
    };

private string Encrypt(string input)
{
    return rules.Aggregate(input, (current, rule) => current.Replace(rule.Item1, rule.Item2));
}

private string Decrypt(string input)
{
    return rules.Aggregate(input, (current, rule) => current.Replace(rule.Item2, rule.Item1));
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks! Can't accept answer before 8 min, I'll do so then

Comment: I've updated the answer adding more convenient sample.

Comment: @Erik Very long 8 minutes... :P

Comment: so sorry for the extensive period of time :P Haven't been on here for a while and I totally forgot those 8 minutes. My bad, sorry!:)

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the result returned by the `output.Replace`, something like:

```
output = input;
output = output.Replace("11", "a");
output = output.Replace("12", "b");
        ...
outputTextBox.Text = output;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.Replace()` method is non-destructive. It doesn't modify the original object. It only returns a new value based on the original with the function applied. So all you have to do is reassign the object to what is returned:

```
output = output.Replace("o", "26");
```

You may also consider creating a couple of dictionaries to handle the mapping and just loop through each letter instead of calling every letter whether it appears in the original string or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness:

In your code use `StringBuilder` instead of `string` for output and input.
Then you would'nt have to reassign in all the replacement lines. Your code should work as -is. Just remove the `output = input` and `input = output` lines from the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` functions

From MSDN:

`Although StringBuilder and String both represent sequences of characters, they are implemented differently. String is an immutable type. That is, each operation that appears to modify a String object actually creates a new string.`

`For routines that perform extensive string manipulation (such as apps that modify a string numerous times in a loop), modifying a string repeatedly can exact a significant performance penalty. The alternative is to use StringBuilder, which is a mutable string class. Mutability means that once an instance of the class has been created, it can be modified by appending, removing, replacing, or inserting characters.`